# how to calculate distance vehicle run from multiple latitude longitude data

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to calculate distance between two points, but my problem is how can I calculate distance from multiple data stored in my database where in single row I am only getting one latitude and one longitude value.

For finding the distance, I need lat long of starting point and end point but in db in single row it has only one lat and long value.

This function works for finding distance, but how can I use it for multiple data from database where I don't have start and end value in single row.

```
CREATE TABLE `distance_calculate` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `distance_calculate` (`id`, `vehicle_id`, `latitude`, `longitude`) 
VALUES(1, 1, '23.247137', '69.700527' ),
(2, 1, '23.252473', '69.685735' ),
(3, 1, '23.249922', '69.686488'),
(4, 1, '23.249045', '69.686204'),
(5, 1, '23.247704', '69.684042'),
(6, 1, '23.246255', '69.683039'),
(7, 1, '23.243978', '69.681671'),
(8, 1, '23.241415', '69.681384');
```

[db in sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5597be/1)

```
id vehicle_id latitude  longitude
 1          1 23.247137 69.700527
 2          1 23.262473 69.686735
 3          1 23.249922 69.686488
 4          1 23.249045 69.686204
 5          1 23.247704 69.684042
 6          1 23.246265 69.683039
 7          1 23.243978 69.681671
 8          1 23.241415 69.681384



function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
      if (($lat1 == $lat2) && ($lon1 == $lon2)) {
        return 0;
      }else {
        $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
        $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
        $dist = acos($dist);
        $dist = rad2deg($dist);
        $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        $unit = strtoupper($unit);

        if ($unit == "K") {
          return ($miles * 1.609344);
        } else if ($unit == "N") {
          return ($miles * 0.8684);
        } else {
          return $miles;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes i know about JOINs.please show me the way how can i achieve using join

Comment: can you show me the example ?

Comment: link for the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5597be/1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demonstration of a JOIN, as requested...

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.id target_id
     , y.latitude target_lat
     , y.longitude target_long 
  FROM distance_calculate x 
  JOIN distance_calculate y 
    ON y.id < x.id;
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| id | vehicle_id | latitude  | longitude | target_id | target_lat | target_long |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+
|  2 |          1 | 23.252473 | 69.685735 |         1 | 23.247137  | 69.700527   |
|  3 |          1 | 23.249922 | 69.686488 |         1 | 23.247137  | 69.700527   |
|  4 |          1 | 23.249045 | 69.686204 |         1 | 23.247137  | 69.700527   |
|  5 |          1 | 23.247704 | 69.684042 |         1 | 23.247137  | 69.700527   |
|  6 |          1 | 23.246255 | 69.683039 |         1 | 23.247137  | 69.700527   |
|  7 |          1 | 23.243978 | 69.681671 |         1 | 23.247137  | 69.700527   |
|  8 |          1 | 23.241415 | 69.681384 |         1 | 23.247137  | 69.700527   |
|  3 |          1 | 23.249922 | 69.686488 |         2 | 23.252473  | 69.685735   |
|  4 |          1 | 23.249045 | 69.686204 |         2 | 23.252473  | 69.685735   |
|  5 |          1 | 23.247704 | 69.684042 |         2 | 23.252473  | 69.685735   |
|  6 |          1 | 23.246255 | 69.683039 |         2 | 23.252473  | 69.685735   |
|  7 |          1 | 23.243978 | 69.681671 |         2 | 23.252473  | 69.685735   |
|  8 |          1 | 23.241415 | 69.681384 |         2 | 23.252473  | 69.685735   |
|  4 |          1 | 23.249045 | 69.686204 |         3 | 23.249922  | 69.686488   |
|  5 |          1 | 23.247704 | 69.684042 |         3 | 23.249922  | 69.686488   |
|  6 |          1 | 23.246255 | 69.683039 |         3 | 23.249922  | 69.686488   |
|  7 |          1 | 23.243978 | 69.681671 |         3 | 23.249922  | 69.686488   |
|  8 |          1 | 23.241415 | 69.681384 |         3 | 23.249922  | 69.686488   |
|  5 |          1 | 23.247704 | 69.684042 |         4 | 23.249045  | 69.686204   |
|  6 |          1 | 23.246255 | 69.683039 |         4 | 23.249045  | 69.686204   |
|  7 |          1 | 23.243978 | 69.681671 |         4 | 23.249045  | 69.686204   |
|  8 |          1 | 23.241415 | 69.681384 |         4 | 23.249045  | 69.686204   |
|  6 |          1 | 23.246255 | 69.683039 |         5 | 23.247704  | 69.684042   |
|  7 |          1 | 23.243978 | 69.681671 |         5 | 23.247704  | 69.684042   |
|  8 |          1 | 23.241415 | 69.681384 |         5 | 23.247704  | 69.684042   |
|  7 |          1 | 23.243978 | 69.681671 |         6 | 23.246255  | 69.683039   |
|  8 |          1 | 23.241415 | 69.681384 |         6 | 23.246255  | 69.683039   |
|  8 |          1 | 23.241415 | 69.681384 |         7 | 23.243978  | 69.681671   |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

I have a function on my database that calculates the distance (in km) between coordinates on Earth. It looks like this:

```
delimiter //
create DEFINER = CURRENT_USER function geo_distance_km (lat1 double, lon1 double, lat2 double, lon2 double) returns double
 begin
   declare R int DEFAULT 6372.8;
   declare phi1 double;
   declare phi2 double;
   declare d_phi double;
   declare d_lambda double;
   declare a double;
   declare c double;
   declare d double;
   set phi1 = radians(lat1);
   set phi2 = radians(lat2);
   set d_phi = radians(lat2-lat1);
   set d_lambda = radians(lon2-lon1);
   set a = sin(d_phi/2) * sin(d_phi/2) +
         cos(phi1) * cos(phi2) *
         sin(d_lambda/2) * sin(d_lambda/2);
   set c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
   set d = R * c;
   return d;
   end;
//
delimiter ;
```

You can use it like this:

```
SELECT x.id source_id
     , y.id target_id
     , geo_distance_km(x.latitude,x.longitude,y.latitude,y.longitude) delta 
  FROM distance_calculate x 
  JOIN distance_calculate y 
    ON y.id < x.id;
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| source_id | target_id | delta            |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
|         2 |         1 |  1.6240400586719 |
|         3 |         1 |  1.4678198641286 |
|         4 |         1 |  1.4790932430399 |
|         5 |         1 |  1.6859300396863 |
|         6 |         1 |  1.7899557954697 |
|         7 |         1 |  1.9588626645576 |
|         8 |         1 |  2.0573621504414 |
|         3 |         2 | 0.29399727258978 |
|         4 |         2 | 0.38429654604457 |
|         5 |         2 | 0.55795904605742 |
|         6 |         2 | 0.74448757446836 |
|         7 |         2 |  1.0321499787366 |
|         8 |         2 |   1.307891566912 |
|         4 |         3 | 0.10177484098073 |
|         5 |         3 | 0.35121611491034 |
|         6 |         3 | 0.53908239576653 |
|         7 |         3 | 0.82430155029471 |
|         8 |         3 |  1.0804876797252 |
|         5 |         4 | 0.26658679033431 |
|         6 |         4 | 0.44825363131558 |
|         7 |         4 | 0.72956618879477 |
|         8 |         4 | 0.98128776490424 |
|         6 |         5 | 0.19100754800257 |
|         7 |         5 | 0.48008313462389 |
|         8 |         5 | 0.75041889106272 |
|         7 |         6 | 0.28929719254935 |
|         8 |         6 |  0.5642986247924 |
|         8 |         7 | 0.28658708452204 |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
```

So, we can see it's quite a short jourey from the Thakarji Lodge Roundabout to the Railway Station Ring Road

Comment: query write you above display multiple duplicate records.

Comment: There are no duplicates here.